# Rank column values based on column1 and put it to column 2 in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have one column named column1 and want to be ranked in column2:

```
Column1  Column2

500       3
1000      4
20        1
310       2
```

what I have tried is to get column values from Column1  and put it to an array:

```
for (int us = 0; us < GridView1.Rows.Count; us++)
                {
double[] doubleArray = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[us].Cells[1].Text) };
```

}

then  sorted it:

```
Array.Sort(doubleArray);
```

then put it in Column2:

```
GridView1.Rows[us].Cells[2].Text += doubleArray[us];
```

This does not making the ranking only gives error;

Comment: You should operate on the data that the grid is bound to instead of messing around with rows and cells. Can you show your data source?

Comment: I get data from textbox and send it to Gridview I have no number data from textbox only text data and convert it to numbers and make some calculations in Gridview so I have to solve this ranking problem in GrdiView....

Comment: isn`t some ranking method in GridView?

Comment: No, there is no built-in ranking functionality in GridView. You should be maintaining a DataSource, like a List<double> or a DataTable or something which you data bind to the grid. It would be trivial to rank the data source and then bind it to the grid.

Comment: How to pass a column into a list can you show me please?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cute problem!

You see, if we fill an array with the ONE column value we want to "rank", then we lose the infomration of what grid row it belongs to.

Obviously the grid can be sorted by LastName, or HotelName or some date - we DO NOT CARE, but STILL need to rank a given column (say a cost value, first name - who cares!!!).

it stands to reason (beyond reason) that the GV current sorting is NOT relevant here!!!

Ranking a particular column value has to occur 100% independent of the current grid sort, and has to occur 100% independent, based on a particular column we want to rank.

As noted, if we pull such values into a array, and then sort? We "lose" what row the value belonged to in the first place.

So, we need to grab/get/have/use/enjoy BOTH the grid row and ALSO the value. We then have to sort, and then put back into GV the value, but ensuring that the value goes back into the correct/current GV row!

So, we need something that will allow us to sort a value + keep current GV row!

This will work:

First, our GV - plane jane markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    CssClass="table table-hover" Width="40%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  HeaderStyle-Width="120"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Night Rate"  DataFormatString="{0:n2}"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText =" Rank (Price)" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"
                    CssClass="btn myshadow"
                    OnClick="cmdEdit_Click"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="cmdRank" runat="server" Text="Rank" Width="111px" 
    CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdRank_Click" />
```

And code to load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        LoadGrid();
}

void LoadGrid()
{
        
    GridView1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So, the gv is ordered by hotel name, but we now need to fill out the "rank" column based on the room price.

This code obviously could/would run after we load the gv, but I have for this answer the code separate.

So, this code should do the trick:

```
protected void cmdRank_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SortedDictionary<decimal, int> MyRank = new SortedDictionary<decimal,int>();

    foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        MyRank.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(gRow.Cells[5].Text),gRow.RowIndex);


    // above is our sorted list, now put rank values into GV
    int i = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<decimal, int> OneRank in MyRank)
    {
        GridViewRow gRow = GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value];
        Label lRank = (Label)gRow.FindControl("lblRank");
        lRank.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        i++;
    }
}
```

And we now see this:

[image]

So, the sorted "Dictionary" item sorts as we add. And we save the "key" as our value to sort.

Now, to be fair, if there is a duplicate value for the rank value, then we have do kluge that.

So, in above, we have numbers, so this would fix this issue:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(gRow.Cells[5].Text);
            while (MyRank.ContainsKey(Price))
                Price += 0.0001m;

        MyRank.Add(Price,gRow.RowIndex);
        }
```

I think if were were to say rank the list by FirstName?

Then we have a string - not a number, and for duplicates in that case?

Hum, I would add the letter "A" to the end in above loop until no match.

## Edit: We now changed the question, new problem and new critera

There is a GREAT lesson here in software development. When you DO NOT define the problem correctly, then you not going to be able to code up a solution. And changing the problem ALSO then means that you wind up re-wirting software. And that is VERY expensive time and money wise.

So, we started out wiht some sample data - but no mention of duplicates. And we also EVEN WITH duplicates ALSO AGAIN changed the critera. In other words, we want not only to rank, but numbers with the same value are to be given the same rank.

The above is a PEFERCT example of why we write out on paper the problme at a hand BEFORE we code. Each new thing, each new critera, each new change will result in a DIFFERENT reuqirement of how the code is written.

Remember, as developers, we don't live to 150 or 200 years old. As a result, we have to "limit" and "optomize" the code we write. Else we spend all day on SO, and we would starve to death, and create much world poverity.

So, as you can see, this question has now morphed into a differnt set of rules, different critera, and a boatload of new concpets and addtions to the problem. And when writing code, we LIMIT to the cretirea reuqired, since as noted, we all don't live to be 200 years old. So, a GREAT example of how not to ask a quesiton,a nd a great exampe of what occures when you do NOT define the problem correcly.

Now that we are armed with new infomration. That new infomration is that dupblics will occur for what we wish to rank, but ALSO a new rule is that duplicate values will be given the same rank value.

In my orginal soltuion, I used the row number for the rank! So, if we are on the 3rd row, then that gets a rank = 3. This saved code, saved variables, and is typical of how developers naturally "optomize" code. (again, we do that based on a given problem, since if one was to code every possbile outcome, then we would not only increase the cost of the solution, but would also likly run out of food and resouces to finish the code or project.

Ok, so armed with this new information, a new problem, new criteria and specifications as to the problem at hand? Then we have to cook up some code that better deals with this expanding scope of a problem.

This is ALSO why it better to make changes to the problem BEFORE we start coding (turns out it is MUCH easer to make changes to the written problem then it is code!!!). And thus we now can grasp and understand WHY we define the problem BEFORE we starting code!!!

so, this code works quite a bit better, and "assumes" that duplicates will and can exist. In the original problem, I did not make such an assumption. As a result we had to add a "band aid" or a "kluge" to now deal with the new issue (duplicates). that band-aid was the incrementing loop (but, we probably REALLY want to get rid of that concept here).

So, the original code was less then ideal, but it WAS based on the question and information provided.

So, I suggest this code. Again, the markup posted above is fine. But, since this problem means the "row" rank is detached from the row number, then we need a counter for the rank now.

so, this code is more workable to this question and problem at hand.

First, we dropped the dictionay, since that works well, but does not handel duplicates.

So, we still need to get/grab/save the "key value", and then the row number (so we can later shove the rank value into that one row).

```
var Ranks = new List<KeyValuePair<decimal,int>>();      
foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(gRow.Cells[5].Text);
    Ranks.Add(new KeyValuePair<decimal,int>(Price, gRow.RowIndex)); 
}            
Ranks = Ranks.OrderBy(o => o.Key).ToList(); 
int Rank = 0;
decimal LastValue = -1;
foreach (KeyValuePair<decimal,int> OneRank in Ranks)
{
    if (LastValue != OneRank.Key)
        Rank++;
    LastValue = OneRank.Key;
    GridViewRow gRow = GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value];
    Label lRank = (Label)gRow.FindControl("lblRank");
    lRank.Text = Rank.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I got an exception at this line: MyRank.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(gRow.Cells[5].Text),gRow.RowIndex);       Input string was not in a correct format....

Comment: Well I was ranking by hotel price which is a decmail. If you going to rank by a string, or int, or double, or whatever? Then change that first (key) value to whatever type you want in your code. So, what data type are you attempting to rank here? (whatever type you need, change that first type to string or whatever you need. As noted, the issue becomes duplicates - but I noted code for that issue, including if you ranking by say a string. I would actually suggest doing this rank against the data source/table you use to fill the GV, but either way is fine. 2nd value is always int for rank.

Comment: I changed it to double   SortedDictionary<double, int> MyRank = new SortedDictionary<double, int>();

                foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    MyRank.Add(Convert.ToDouble(gRow.Cells[3].Text), gRow.RowIndex);

                }     but still get other error: An entry with the same key already exists.

Comment: Well, as I pointed out, do you have duplicates in that list? If yes, then add that 2nd code stub - just add 0.01 each time you hit a match - the number used does not display, so add the 2nd code stub to prevent duplicates. I mean if two values are the same, then what do you want to do? (have same rank, or have some order for those values that match???).

Comment: now I do not get error but ranking column doesn`t show any key or values it is empty

Comment: You have to post more code, and maybe even markup. The post code works fine, so it not clear what you missing here. I mean, the posted code is the concept, the idea, and from that the code is rather simple. To be fair, we should be operating on the data source used, not trying to use the Grid as a "data store". So, really, the code should process against the data table. But, regardless, post the code you have - without that, this becomes a silly guessing game, right? So, edit your post - include more code. And does your data have duplicates or not? (you not even answered that question).

Comment: Now it is working it gives the ranking but where are repetitions I want to give the same ranking score example: price:500   ranking:5   if  price repeats I want to give the same ranking:5 in this case....

Comment: If the rank value is an integer why I get exeption that input string is a not correct format which I get from template field which shows ranking...

Comment: put a break-point in your code - or even a debug.print - what is the value before you attempt the conversion? However, see me edit - I have posted a code solution that better reflects all of the new rules and additional scope of this software problem. However, as I noted, really 100X better to do this against the data source and process that.  but, once again, without you have provided code, and more information, then all you doing is creating more world poverty by not supplying such information. But, do see the new code I posted, it should deal with duplicates far better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a hurry and do not intend to read above full answer (by @albert-d-kallal). The required 'code' is at the END OF the above best explained answer.